# Mac wants to connect to an old / dead server

Tags: itunes, mac, time-capsule, webserver

My mac is still trying to connect to an old Time Capsule that doesn't exist anymore.

I went to Finder -> Go -> Connect to servers and could see the old TimeCapsule server address:

"afp://Timey%20Wimey%20Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local"

(It was not listed in the favorites box however)

Running OS 10.12.1

Details: A year ago I had a time capsule set up with my mac. I had my iTunes library on there but the stress killed the hard drive in the Time Capsule.  I have since done away with the TimeCapsule but my mac continues to search for the server.

afp://Timey%20Wimey%20Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac is not searching for the server. When you go to "Connect to Server", it automatically puts in the last used address. That does not mean it is actively searching for the server. If you see a blue status bar that says "connecting to ...", that means your Mac is searching for a server.